# net start telnet command gives service name is invalid

Tags: windows

I'm trying to learn about network and It says that I can start  Telnet service by typing `net start telnet` in command line. However, I get "The service name is invalid" error. I tried `config tlntsvr start = auto` and it still doesn't work.Here is a picture:

[image: ta]

Comment: Telnet server has been deprecated on Windows 10. You can still enable the client but the server no longer exists.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017678/feature-telnet-server-not-available-in-windows-10